# retrieving data from sqlite database and displaying it in another class through "OnItemClick"

Tags: android, sqlite

I want that as I click on list item the application should load another class and then display the required data on textview by retrieving the data from sqlite database

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(DictionaryActivity.this,
            WordDetails.class);
    // Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
    id = wordList.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
    intent.putExtra("Word_ID", id);
    // cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

this code is in WordDetails class

```
wordId = getIntent().getIntExtra("WORD_ID", -1);
if (wordId == -1) {
    mean = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mean);
    mean.setText("Error");
} else {
    SQLiteDatabase db = (new DatabaseHelper(this))
            .getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
            "SELECT _id ,word, mean FROM Meanings WHERE _id = ?",
            new String[] { "" + wordId });
    if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        mean = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mean);
        mean.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mean")));
    }
}
```

When I click on an item "Error" word is being displayed which is supposed to show, but `wordTd` equals -1. Why this `wordId` is not getting correct value? Thanks for your help.

Comment: FYI, after you cut & paste code into your question, highlight the code again and press Ctrl+K to format it as a code block. Use ` for snippets of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'keys' used when putting `Intent` extras are case sensitive. You are putting the id as...

```
intent.putExtra("Word_ID", id);
```

...but then trying to get it with...

```
wordId = getIntent().getIntExtra("WORD_ID", -1);
```

In other words you're putting `Word_ID` and trying to get `WORD_ID`. Change the code so they're both the same and it should work.

Comment: Good catch (Upvote). I though the `id` was incorrect, but it's just a redundant method...

Comment: After changing WORD_ID to Word_ID I m still getting the same result

Comment: Please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33029908/fetch-data-from-sqlite-to-new-class

Answer (score 1):

The `id` passed by default to the OnItemClickListener is the row's unique id from the database, there is no need to get it in this manner:

```
id = wordList.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
```

Change your OnItemClickListener to this:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(DictionaryActivity.this, WordDetails.class);
    intent.putExtra("Word_ID", id);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: after doing this I m still getting the same result

Comment: Thanks for telling this.Its really helpful for me