# Two arrays in one TextView in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have a question that I would love to get an answer on.

I have two arrays, let's say:

```
String[] name = {"Name Nameson", "Second Name"};
String[] number = {"111 11 111", "222 22 222"};
```

I want my ListView to have two TextViews into one item.(I tried to illustrate this with a picture).

I manage to get f.ex. my name array into the listview with a simple

```
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_name, name));
```

I have my main.xml with my ListView in it, single_name.xml and single_number.xml in my layout-folder.

Since I'm new to this site I'm not allowed to add a picture, I will try to illustrate it here:

---

HEADER

---

(item one)

Name Nameson

111 11 111

---

(item two)

Second Name

222 22 222

---

And this continues depending on quantity of contacts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to build a custom Adapter as well a custom view to represent each row in your List.

Here's an example of a simple adapter for a listview with 2 textviews and an imageview. Modify as you see fit to include your header and take out the imageview

```
package com.aquarius.customlistviewproject;


public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


 private ArrayList<String> album_names;

private ArrayList<String> num_photos;

 public Activity context;

public LayoutInflater inflater;

 public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> album_names ,     ArrayList<String> num_photos){

super();
this.album_names = album_names;
this.num_photos = num_photos;
this.context = context;
this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}


public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return album_names.size();
}

public class ViewHolder{

    ImageView thumbnail;
    TextView  title;
    TextView photos;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);

        holder.thumbnail = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgViewLogo);
        holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewTitle);
        holder.photos = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDescription);


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    else
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        holder.thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.imgview_drawable);

        holder.title.setText(album_names.get(position));
        holder.photos.setText(num_photos.get(position));
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I have one more question. Will this class actually make something on the screen or will I need another class that updates the UI with this?

Comment: This is only the code you will use for your adapter. You will still need an Activity class that's responsible for setting up your data sources, instantiating your adapter and setting the data to the list. All of this is really simple though, fortunately lol. Have a look at this tutorial on my blog. http://jadebyfield.blogspot.com/

Comment: You can leave it out all the fancy xml stuff and just pay attention to the adapter class and the activity that sets everything up for you. Hope this helps a bit man, cheers.

Comment: Thanks Jade, I briefly cruised through your blog on custom listviews and it seems awesome and simple, actually. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Wow. This was awesome Jade. Thanks alot again. Something that took me hour after hour of searching was done so simple on you blog.

Comment: Thanks man. Keep up the good work and thanks for checking the blog out!

Comment: Hi again Jade, do you also have an example of onItemClicks? I'm making it work but I have to know the unique ID of my rows in SQLite, since they are important data that will update the next activity. I now loop through the ID's and I'm putting them into an array and making them 'Invisibe' on my item_listrow.xml. Is there a good way to get the value from that invisible info?

Comment: hmm..I'm not 100% understand your question. Are you trying to correspond the ID of the listitem that was clicked(0, 1, 2, etc) to the unique ID of the row at that position in your database? I would guess that it depends on how your DBHelper class is set up and what methods you have handy. You could also have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300089/retrieving-data-from-sqlite-database-and-displaying-it-in-another-class-through

Answer (score 1):

you have to build your own adapter.

You can modify this one for your use, it uses viewholder pattern for performance increase.

```
public class WifiListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Wifi> entries;
    private Location location;
    private boolean withDistance;

    public static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView ssid;
        public TextView crypt;
        public TextView distance;

    }

    public WifiListAdapter(ArrayList<Wifi> entries, Location location) {
        this.entries = entries;
        this.location = location;
        withDistance = true;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return entries.size();
    }

    public Wifi getItem(int position) {
        return entries.get(position);
    }


    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            vi =  MyApplication.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.wifi_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ssid = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.wifi_list_ssid);
            holder.crypt = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.wifi_list_crypt);
            holder.distance = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.wifi_list_distance);

            vi.setTag(holder);


        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
        }
        Wifi wifi = entries.get(position);

        holder.ssid.setText(wifi.ssid);

        StringBuilder cryptString = new StringBuilder(20);

        if(wifi.wep == 1)
            cryptString.append("WEP ");
        if(wifi.wpa == 1)
            cryptString.append("WPA ");
        if(wifi.wpa2 == 1)
            cryptString.append("WPA2 ");
        if(wifi.wps == 1)
            cryptString.append("WPS ");
        if(wifi.ess == 1)
            cryptString.append("ESS");


        String distanceString;
        if(withDistance) {
            float[] results = new float[1];
            Location.distanceBetween(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), wifi.lat, wifi.lng, results);
            distanceString = MyApplication.formatDistance(results[0]);
        } else
            distanceString = "unknown";

        holder.distance.setText(distanceString);

        holder.crypt.setText(cryptString.toString().trim());
        //holder.distance.setText(results[0] + "");


        holder.ssid.setTag(position);
        holder.crypt.setTag(position);
        holder.distance.setTag(position);


        return vi;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom adapter of

```
ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String,String>>
```