# Displaying an image in a listview

Tags: android, json

How can I display an image and string text from JSON in a listview?

```
// new HashMap
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

String imageName = c.getString("avater");
URL url1 = new URL(imageName);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();

InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); 

//updating listview with the parsed items
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    Inboxtest.this,
    entryList,
    R.layout.inboxlist,
    new String[] { TAG_QUERY, TAG_RESULT, timesent, icon },
    new int[] { R.id.textView1, R.id.textView3, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView4 }
);

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I need to put image on this list.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Lazy Loading using [ImageLoader](http://androidimageloader.com/) for showing images in ListView. By this way your UI will remain responsive.

Use a wrapper to store the Image Name and its URL.
Put this into an arraylist and then use this arraylist in the ListAdapter.

Create a row (in xml) for the ListView having textview and imageview. Set the image name and image to it in the getView of your custom ListAdapter.

Try it out. I'll share the code if you get stuck.

Happy Coding!

Comment: i do row with text and image but i can`t display image in this row

Comment: share the xml of your row. Is there any error coming at run time?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom listview_row layout file via xml..and inflate that custom row by creating an adapter that binds your parsed JSON data to the list, along with the image. I answered a very similar question a few days ago, so I won't re-post that code here but I will link you to the question. Also, I posted a link to blog post about how to go about creating a custom list with text, images and a custom adapter. Hope this helps man.

Previous SO question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13186855/949266

Find my blog post here
http://jadebyfield.blogspot.com/